# Python - Crawler to Extract Data from Tables

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, html-table

I am trying to extract customer reviews section from Agoda (http://www.agoda.com/grand-hyatt-taipei/hotel/taipei-tw.html). The data I am interested are under the 'div id = "hotelreview-panel" ', which include the number of reviews made by different types of traveler (eg. Business traveler) and the corresponding KPI scales (eg. Value for Money) for each type of traveler.

There are two problems I have:

(1) I cannot reach the right table through the find function of BeautifulSoup. There exists the table class "customer-review-category-issues" but it kept returning none.

```
import requests
import math
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

HotelNames = ['grand-hyatt-taipei']

with open('agoda_hotel_reviews.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    for iHotel in HotelNames: 
        url = "http://www.agoda.com/"+iHotel+"/hotel/taipei-tw.html"
        res = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

        table_review = soup.find("table", {"class" : "customer-review-category-issues"})
        record_rev = []

        for row in table_review.findAll('tr'):
            col = row.findAll('td')
            rev_issue = col[1].string.split('\n').strip()[0]
            rev_count = col[1].string.split('\n').strip()[1]
            record_rev.extend([rev_issue], [rev_count])

     filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='|', lineterminator='\n')
     filewriter.writerow(record_rev)
```

(2) How do I extract the KPI when I switch to different traveler types so my returning list become something like [All reviews, 35, 8.1, 9.2, 9.0, 9.1, 9.1, 8.3, Business travelers, 10, 7.8, 8.6, 8.4, 8.6, 8.6, 7.2], that is [Traveler Type, # of Review, KPI 1 (value for money), KPI 2 (location), ... KPI 6]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is: reviews and other parts of the page are loaded dynamically with additional XHR requests to the service API. If you open up developer tools and filter XHR requests only, you'll see:

[image]

If you are planning to stay with `requests`+`BeautifulSoup`, you might be interested in simulating requests to "GetReviewScore" and "GetReviewComments" endpoints.

Or, you may take a more "high-level" approach and automate a real browser with [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/).

Comment: That's a huge help! Thank you!